# Iphone: Populating UITableView or CustomCells from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I need your advice in solving this issue:

I am parsing a XML File and puting the results in NSMutableDictionarys which I put in NSMutableArray:

The NSMutableArray with the Dictionarys looks like this:

```
Res: (
    {
    adresse = "Wielandg 36";
    email = "office@tierarzt-riegelnegg.at";
    latitude = "47.063065712289";
    longitude = "15.439759954196";
    ordiname = "Kleintierpraxis Jakomini Dipl Tzt Riegelnegg Gerfried";
    ort = Graz;
    plz = 8010;
    tel = "+43316830438";
    tierarztid = 3;
    web = "http://www.tierarzt-riegelnegg.at";
},
    {
    adresse = "Rechbauerstr 3";
    email = "glantschnig@kleintierambulatorium.at";
    fax = "+43316321156";
    latitude = "47.070320493663";
    longitude = "15.448505434137";
    ordiname = "KLEINTIERAMBULATORIUM - Dr. Simon Glantschnig";
    ort = Graz;
    plz = 8010;
    tel = "+43316321156";
    tierarztid = 2;
    web = "http://www.kleintierambulatorium.at";
},
    {
    adresse = "Humboldtstr 7";
    latitude = "47.079379100630";
    longitude = "15.440064023548";
    ordiname = "Bernhart Barbara Dr";
    ort = Graz;
    plz = 8010;
    tel = "+43316684912";
    tierarztid = 4;
}
```

Well this part works really fine! Now I put "ordiname" inside a UITableView, and when the User clicks the name, I am opening a "DetailView" where I want to show the results of the dictionary inside an UITableView or CustomCells - NSLog for this works fine - I can see the whole selected dictionary in the DetailView. Presenting in the TableView or CustomCells has to be done dynamically, as not all of the possible entries have to be filled (for example: Fax is not mandatory).

How can I achieve this? The order of the NSMutableDictionary is always the same...

Thanks for any help and advice!

BR,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to have the DetailView adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol and add the following methods,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myDictionary count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *name = [[myDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSString *value = [myDictionary objectForKey:name];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeReusableCellWithItentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if(!cell) {
        //create cell
    }
    //set the name and value
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", name, value];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the only trouble however is that the [myDictionary allKeys] creates newer NSArrays. Although they will not leak, its still something to be aware of.

Comment: I am impressed! Thanks a lot! Now a short question: what would you do to display custom images to each row? BR, Stefan

Comment: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/ this one seems to explain it quite fine. but if you are having trouble, you might have to create a new question for that as its quite off topic on this one.